# opera default theme become black ?

Tags: windows-vista, themes, opera, opera-10

I am using Opera 10.5 on my Windows Vista Aero theme , and the tabs color have black color .
why that is there a un-compatibility between Vista and opera ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your Tools -> Appearance. Install a new theme which comes with different colors or just try reset your settings altogether. (You can do that by moving the `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Opera` and the `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Opera` folder to somewhere else to give this a try. (If nothing happens, just place it back.) 
Anyway, Vista is totally compatible with Opera.